# Error al retornar un array con JSON

Tags: php, javascript, json, array

Buenas tardes estoy intentando devolver un array y me retorna este error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (controlador.js:66)
    at u (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
```

el tema es que el error retorna cuando la consola tiene mas de una fila, si la consulta a la base de datos trae una sola fila hay si se ejecuta bien.

Les comparto mi codigo JS y PHP:

Este es mi código en PHP:

```
  $sql=("SELECT usr.usrcod,usr.usrnombres,usr.usrapellidos 
        FROM tbl_usuarios usr 
        ");
  $result= mysqli_query($cnx,$sql);
  if(!$result){
    die('Error de consulta.'. mysql_error($cnx));
  }

  $resp = array();
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $resp[] = array(
      'error'=>false,
      'usrcod' => $row['usrcod'],
      'usrnombres' => $row['usrnombres'],
      'usrapellidos' => $row['usrapellidos']
    );
  }
  $respstring = json_encode($resp);
  echo $respstring;
```

Este es mi codigo en JS:

```
function cargarUsrRegistrados(nombre) {
    var ent = localStorage.getItem('ent');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'modelos/buscar.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { nombre, ent },
        success: function(response) {
            if (!response.error) {
                let tot = JSON.parse(response)
                console.log(tot);
                let template = '';
                tot.forEach(tot => {
                    template += `
                     <li><a href="#" class="task-item">${tot.usrnombres}</a></li>
                    `
                });
                $('#task-result').show();
                $('#container').html(template);
            } else { console.log("Error en funcion") }
      }
  })
}
Ayuda Por favor.
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: saludos podrias colocar luego de success y antes del if....console.log(response); para ver como trae tu response y darte una mejor respuesta..

Comment: Trae Vacío, por ese vacío se genera el error solo que no se porque trae vacío, si me puedes ayudar te lo agradezco =(

Comment: ¿Qué contienen las variables `$respstring` y `$resp` en el código php?